# I was wondering if its possible to check what an if statement evaluates to before stepping into it using debugger visual studio code

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I have this C code that I was working on and honestly I do not understand how it exactly works (I never used if statements like this before). Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int x = 2, y = 0;
  if (x = ++y)
  {
    printf("%d is equal to %d\n", x,y);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d is not equal %d", x, y);
  }
}
```

For some reason it seems that the assignment operator is also acting as an equality operator? Because when it evaluates X would be 1 and Y would be 1 and therefore it'll go to the first body, inside if. However if I do `x = y++`, it will go to the second statement. Just confused me a bit because isn't equality supposed to be `==` Not `=`

Comment: read up on the action of the pre and post increment operator (++). Assignment (`=`) is also an operator and has a result. Who has typed this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "=" operator return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431631/what-does-the-operator-return).  It provides an explanation for precisely this use case.

Comment: @rioV8 It was a university assignment to figure out what this code would output and why. And i was just stuck and couldn't really understand since i never used the assignment operator inside an if statement.

Comment: using the operator precedence find out what these expressions do: `a=b=c=d=3` and `a=1+b=1+c=1+d=3`

Comment: @rioV8 I believe for the first expression it will assign d to 3 first and then go right to left assigning c to d and b to c and a to b. For the second one i think it would go d = 3 and then d+1 so c would be 4 and then b would be 5 and a would be 6. I think. Not veerrry sure on the second one.

Comment: the first one is worded wrong: assign 3 to d, d to c, c to b and b to a. If you place braces it is more clear `a=(b=(c=(d=3)))` and `a=1+(b=1+(c=1+(d=3)))`, so `=` is an operator that constructs an expression with a value, just like `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a semantic fix of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int x = 2, y = 0;
  if (x = ++y)
  {
    printf("y has been incremented and copied to x, which is now non-zero\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("y has been incremented and copied to x, which is now zero\n");
  }
}
```

---

and

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int x = 2, y = 0;
  if (x = y++)
  {
    printf("y has been copied to x and then y incremented, x is now non-zero (y was non-zero)\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("y has been copied to x and then y incremented, x is now zero (y was zero)\n");
  }
}
```

---

As a general principle I advocate the use of **Yoda expressions** where a non-assignable value is put on the left e.g. `if (1 == x)`.  This guards against accidental assignment.

Comment: Ok so to clarify, Since in the first case x would be equal to 1, in C, that would equate to true. the assignment operator and the ++y happen before the conditional. Strictly speaking. The conditional is `if (x)`, and the rest is operations before the conditional is evaluated. Is that correct? Sooo in the second case since x would be 0, `if (x)` would be false

Comment: Yep.  Don't forget to upvote the answer and check out the C/C++ FAQ - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info and the site tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour